# MAMP for windows - permissions error: You don't have permission to access /form/< on this server

Tags: permissions, mamp

I have recently installed MAMP pro 3.2.2, and starting to learn how to use it.

I am also learning how to make web page php forms. And MAMP appears to be a way for me to test web page designs.

I am starting with a basic exercise that is meant to echo a name and email address being entered into the form. I'm getting a permissions issue when I test the following web page code:

"index.html" file contents:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="write.php" method="post">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The screenshots of the issue I see are:

[basic form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Pwi.jpg)

[permissions issue screenshot after clicking submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itxdw.jpg)

I am likely making some rookie error. Could someone please help to point me in the right direction so that I can get around this permissions issue? Some kind help on this would be very greatly appreciated.

I will add that - When I test a simpler 'form' (using the following code plus php file), the echoing works just fine. That is, the following combination works fine:

"index.html" file contents:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="write.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

"write.php" file contents:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I can also say that I managed to install a WordPress site with MAMP. So now, I'm focusing on trying to find out how to remedy the permissions issue associated with the basic "form" exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies everyone, I finally figured out for myself what my problem was.

I now understand that php code (commands) need to be run within a .php file. So my code below needs to be inside a .php file (and not an .html file)

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST)): ?>
Welcome, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); ?>!<br>
Your email is <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]); ?>.<br>
<?php else: ?>
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So..... as I expected, it is rookie error on my part. So..... when script code contains php commands (ie. enclosed within the symbols like....  ..... it is necessary to have that script within a .php file (not a .html file).